In popos, I have installed texlive-full, yet I am still getting errors saying styles not installed?
sudo apt install texlive-full
texlive-full is already the newest version (2021.20220204-1).

pdflatex main.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21> (./dccpaper.cls
Document Class: dccpaper 1996/09/19
*** 1996/09/19 Class for DCC conference papers ***
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/epsfig.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))

! LaTeX Error: File `citesort.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

What am I doing wrong? I just looked, and found a file online, installed it in the directory, so I have the document building, but I am kind of startled that an IEEE conference would give a template with no mention of a dependency like that. Is this really the way?

'Nothing' - where have you found citesort from? It's not on CTAN so not in TeX Live.

related https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2017-March/039802.html ? It seem to be available from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex209/contrib/misc?lang=en in case you want to manually install it.

LaTeX classes, styles or templates from conferences and journals are often outdated, incompatible, badly coded etc., so indeed trying to fix things manually is really the way. The DCC class is from 1996, that is almost 30 years old so it is not surprising that some things stop working. In the template also the epsfig and color packages are used which are superseded by modern counterparts, for example.

You can also try to modernize the template (main.tex) by removing the outdated packages, and leaving the class (dccpaper.cls) as it is, since you only need to submit the resulting pdf for the conference you can make changes as long as the intended formatting is preserved. And even when the conference does ask for the source files then your new main.tex will most likely be approved as long as it is compatible with the original .cls file.

@JosephWright It was just a random github repo, found via google. I can't believe there was a dependency on some random file not included in their package, which is why I asked, but that's all I found
